# How to render React template in string as DOM using NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx, next.js13

I have some template which use React Component e.g:

```html
<Section>
  <div>
    <HelloWorld />
  </div>
  <Hello name="my name" />
</Section>
```

and some components defined in my code such as :

```
export function Section({children}) {
  return <div className="custom-class">{children}</div>
}

export function HelloWorld() {
  return <div>Hello World</div>
}

export function Hello({name}) {
   return <div>Hello {name}</div>
}
```

I would like to pass the template (as a string) to react and make it generate the correct DOM using the components I declared in my codebase. How can I do this ?

I tried using the props `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but it only read raw html.

I also looked at `next-mdx-remote` https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-remote which is almost what I need but for mdx.

Is there a straight solution or a library that exist who solve this issue ?